# How do you post a form in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I am trying out Phonegap and have a very simple app in html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>&nbsp;</title>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Trying out Phonegap</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <h3>Sign in here</h3>
                <form>
                    Username
                    <input type='text' name='username'>
                    Password
                    <input type='text' name='password'>
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I don't know how to handle the form submission. Should I post directly to an external url api.myserver.com/signin or should I be using JQuery to post the fields to an API and then change to another view based on the response? Any comments or code snippets would be really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use javascript/jQuery to retrieve the values of the inputs in the form when the submit event fires, then use ajax to send the values to a remote server and wait for a response.

Depending on the response, you can proceed on whichever way you like; show dialogs, change pages, etc.

Comment: Have you any link for example