# how to fetch post() method parameter through javascript?

Tags: javascript, post

i'm working on mobile development and developing pure JavaScript, CSS and HTML code, cant use any server side scripting like PHP, Jsp n all since i have to feed it in phone-gap. I just want to know how i can fetch the post parameters through JavaScript(like in jsp we fetch it through request.getparameter) ? please help me out guys thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to read POST data from the request that generated the current page using client side JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind you have the change the way your app will work. But if you really want to send your form on a page, you can use GET method and retreive parameters from the URL

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/get-query-params-object/

The normal way : on form submit you should have a JS function, and this function has to do the job.

Do not forget to use Google/Stackoverflow.com you should find your answer ;-)

[How do you post a form in Phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960826/how-do-you-post-a-form-in-phonegap)

Comment: that's not the way, i know about the get() n parsing url stuff,, m asking about the post() because i don't want to send data through url since its confidential. btw thanks and leave now instead of form submission m start using session ans button.click() event it works.

Comment: In my mind, inside a phonegap app GET is not less secure than POST.
But I think you have to think about you app structure. If you have a one page app you do not need GET/POST. If you use multi-pages app you should have bad surprise ,-)